# Where to find Docker container filesystem

Tags: docker

I am trying to dockerize my python script which is called `QC.py`. to do so, I made a `Dockerfile` which looks like this:

```
FROM python:3

ADD qc.py /

RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install sklearn

CMD [ "python", "./qc.py" ]
```

I built the image using this command:

```
docker build -t qc .
```

and then run it using this command:

```
docker run qc
```

without using docker the script works perfectly (I can see the process and at the end it returns "it is done", this is what I added to make sure the script is working) and the output is some `pdf` files. when I use docker using the mentioned command and `Dockerfile`, still it works and I see the process but I do not see the pdf files. I think they are in the container filesystem. do you know how to access the pdf files?

Answer (score 2):

The Python script is execute inside the docker container and this is also where the output of your script is located.

#### Docker images creation

The Dockerfile is correct, concerning the installation of the required environment (numpy, sklearn). Place the script in a separate directory e.g. `qc` to avoid collisions with the container filesystem.

```
FROM python:3

ADD qc.py /qc/

RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install sklearn

CMD [ "python", "./qc/qc.py" ]
```

```
docker build -t qc .
```

#### Add volumes to running container

Run the container and mount a `output` folder inside the container:

```
docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/qc/output qc
```

The run command mount the current directory to the `/qc/output` folder inside the container. The `qc.py` needs to be modified to place its output inside the `output` folder.

Then the output of script is placed inside the local folder.